# To use package properly, how to arrange directory, file name, unit test file?

Tags: go

My source files tree is like this:

```
/src
  /pkg
    /foo
      foo.go
      foo_test.go
```

Inside `foo.go`:

```
package foo

func bar(n int) {
    ...
}
```

inside `foo_test.go`:

```
package foo

func testBar(t *testing.T) {
    bar(10)
    ...
}
```

My questions are:

1. Does package name relates to directory name, source file name?
2. If there is only one source file for a package, need I put it in a directory?
3. Should I put `foo.go` and `foo_test.go` in the same package?
4. In the `foo_test.go`, as it's in the same package as `foo.go`, I didn't import `foo`. But when I compile `foo_test.go` with 6g, it says `bar() is undefined`. What should I do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1 - The language spec says the following:

> A set of files sharing the same PackageName form the implementation of a package. An implementation may require that all source files for a package inhabit the same directory.

So it seems that there is no requirement on the naming of files / directories, but it would be safer to put all file that form a package in one directory.

2 - Obviously the file must be in some directory. I assume you mean "*should I put it in a subdirectory of `src`*?" It seems to me based on the above quote that you could have all your files in `src` directly if you really wanted to.

3 - Yes.

4 - Use [`go test`](http://golang.org/cmd/go/#Test_packages)