# Organizing a multiple-file Go project

Tags: go

Note: this question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182469/to-use-package-properly-how-to-arrange-directory-file-name-unit-test-file), but two years is a very long time in Go history.

What is the standard way to organize a Go project during development ?

My project is a single package `mypack`, so I guess I put all the .go files in a `mypack` directory.

But then, I would like to test it during development so I need at least a file declaring the `main` package, so that I can do `go run trypack.go`

How should I organize this ? Do I need to do `go install mypack` each time I want to try it ?

Comment: This brief screencast is awesome: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XCsL89YtqCs

Comment: [This](http://www.goinggo.net/2013/07/how-packages-work-in-go-language.html) is another helpful link in understanding how to organize a project with packages. Easier to follow than the official How to Write go Code I think.

Comment: For the new Go modules system, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57314494/11210494) covers module structure, arranging packages within a module, whether or not to have multiple modules in single repository, etc.  Eventually, the official ["How to Write Go Code"](http://golang.org/doc/code.html) intro document will be updated for modules, but that hasn't happened yet. (If you are new to Go and new to Go modules, it is still worth reading that "How to Write Go Code" document before reading more about modules given much of the modules documentation assumes familiarity with GOPATH).

Answer (score 177, accepted):

I would recommend reviewing this page on [How to Write Go Code](http://golang.org/doc/code.html)

It documents both how to structure your project in a `go build` friendly way, and also how to write tests. Tests do not need to be a cmd using the `main` package. They can simply be TestX named functions as part of each package, and then `go test` will discover them.

The structure suggested in that link in your question is a bit outdated, now with the release of Go 1. You no longer would need to place a `pkg` directory under `src`. The only 3 spec-related directories are the 3 in the root of your GOPATH:  bin, pkg, src . Underneath src, you can simply place your project `mypack`, and underneath that is all of your .go files including the mypack_test.go

`go build` will then build into the root level pkg and bin.

So your GOPATH might look like this:

```
~/projects/
    bin/
    pkg/
    src/
      mypack/
        foo.go
        bar.go
        mypack_test.go
```

`export GOPATH=$HOME/projects`

```
$ go build mypack
$ go test mypack
```

Update: as of >= Go 1.11, the [Module](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules) system is now a standard part of the tooling and the GOPATH concept is close to becoming obsolete.

Comment: Use $HOME instead of ~ when exporting variables.

Comment: Why is $HOME recommended over ~ when exporting variables?

Comment: Because ~ is not a variable, just an alias.

Comment: @425nesp Johan is mistaken -- it's not. Shells vary, but [bash expands `~` when setting environmental variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html), and so does the busybox bourne shell, for instance. Try it yourself: `export BOB=~ && env | grep ^BOB` will yield `BOB=/your/homedir`

Comment: `$HOME` works in more shells then `~`, for example in `fish`

Answer (score 61):

jdi has the right information concerning the use of `GOPATH`. I would add that if you intend to have a binary as well you might want to add one additional level to the directories.

```
~/projects/src/
    myproj/
        mypack/
            lib.go
            lib_test.go
            ...
        myapp/
            main.go
```

running `go build myproj/mypack` will build the `mypack` package along with it's dependencies
running `go build myproj/myapp` will build the `myapp` binary along with it's dependencies which probably includes the `mypack` library.

Comment: This would make sense, of course, if he did actually have a main cmd. Seemed like he is just creating a library package.

Answer (score 51):

I have studied a number of Go projects and there is a fair bit of variation. You can kind of tell who is coming from C and who is coming from Java, as the former dump just about everything in the projects root directory in a `main` package, and the latter tend to put everything in a `src` directory. Neither is optimal however. Each have consequences because they affect import paths and how others can reuse them.

To get the best results I have worked out the following approach.

```
myproj/
  main/
    mypack.go
  mypack.go
```

Where `mypack.go` is `package mypack` and `main/mypack.go` is (obviously) `package main`.

If you need additional support files you have two choices. Either keep them all in the root directory, or put *private* support files in a `lib` subdirectory. E.g.

```
myproj/
  main/
    mypack.go
  myextras/
    someextra.go
  mypack.go
  mysupport.go
```

Or

```
myproj.org/
  lib/
    mysupport.go
    myextras/
      someextra.go
  main/
    mypack.go
  mypage.go
```

Only put the files in a `lib` directory if they are not intended to be imported by another project. In other words, if they are *private* support files. That's the idea behind having `lib` --to separate public from private interfaces.

Doing things this way will give you a nice import path, `myproj.org/mypack` to reuse the code in other projects. If you use `lib` then internal support files will have an import path that is indicative of that, `myproj.org/lib/mysupport`.

When building the project, use `main/mypack`, e.g. `go build main/mypack`. If you have more than one executable you can also separate those under `main` without having to create separate projects. e.g. `main/myfoo/myfoo.go` and `main/mybar/mybar.go`.

Comment: Idomatic is to use a `cmd/nameOfMyExecutable` sub-directory for the main package (only need `cmd/…` if you have multiple commands; see `golang.org/x/tools/cmd`; otherwise it's common to swap it around and have `main.go` at the top level). The way you have it `go install` will create a "main" (or "main.exe") executable. Also, idiomatic is to use an `internal` sub-directory for a sub-package internal to the package/program that's not meant to be used elsewhere (it is expected future versions of Go will enforce no one else importing `internal` packages done this way).

Answer (score 21):

I find very useful to understand how to organize code in Golang this chapter http://www.golang-book.com/11 of the book written by Caleb Doxsey

Comment: Thank you! Let me read the book. I will code after two weeks.

Answer (score 14):

There doesn't seem to be a standard way of organizing Go projects but https://golang.org/doc/code.html specifies a best practice for most projects.  jdi's answer is good but if you use github or bitbucket and you have additional libraries as well, you should create the following structure:

```
~/projects/
bin/
pkg/
src/
  github.com/
    username/
        mypack/
            foo.go
            bar.go
            mypack_test.go
        mylib/
            utillib.go
            utillib_test.go
```

By doing it this way, you can have a separate repository for mylib that can be used for other projects and can be retrieved by "go get".  Your mypack project can import your library using "github.com/username/mylib".  For more information:

http://www.alexvictorchan.com/2014/11/06/go-project-structure/

Answer (score 7):

Keep the files in the same directory and use `package main` in all files.

```
myproj/
   your-program/
      main.go
      lib.go
```

Then run:

```
~/myproj/your-program$ go build && ./your-program
```

Comment: How can this work? Your main.go needs to be package main; presumably lib.go is in a different package, then the go tool complains that you can't have two packages in a single folder.

Comment: @I82Much OP asks for how to divide one package, the main program, to many files. lib.go is in the same package in this case.

Comment: @Gustav, I have the same question. It seems if I put package main in lib.go, in main.go, I cannot call functions defined in lib.go.

Comment: @ElgsQianChen The methods need to be public, it has to start with a capital letter. E.g. MyMethod() or MyStruct{...}.

Comment: @Gustav yes, the method name is capitalized. It seems it works in any packages but main.

Answer (score 7):

Let's explorer how the `go get repository_remote_url` command manages the project structure under `$GOPATH`. If we do a `go get github.com/gohugoio/hugo` It will clone the repository under

> $GOPATH/src/**repository_remote/user_name/project_name**

---

> $GOPATH/src/**github.com/gohugoio/hugo**

This is a nice way to create your *initial project path*. Now let's explorer what are the project types out there and how their inner structures are organized. All golang projects in the community can be categorized under

- `Libraries` (no executable binaries)
- `Single Project` (contains only 1 executable binary)
- `Tooling Projects` (contains multiple executable binaries)

---

Generally golang project files can be packaged under *any design principles* such as [DDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design), [POD](https://www.ardanlabs.com/blog/2017/02/package-oriented-design.html)

Most of the available go projects follows this [Package Oriented Design](https://www.ardanlabs.com/blog/2017/02/package-oriented-design.html)

[Package Oriented Design](https://www.ardanlabs.com/blog/2017/02/package-oriented-design.html) encourage the developer to keeps the implementation only inside it's own packages, other than the `/internal` package those packages can't can communicate with each other

---

### Libraries

- Projects such as [database drivers](https://github.com/go-mgo/mgo), [qt](https://github.com/therecipe/qt) can put under this category.
- Some libraries such as [color](https://github.com/fatih/color), [now](https://github.com/jinzhu/now) follows a flat structure without any other packages.
- Most of these library projects manages a package called **internal**.
- `/internal` package is mainly used to hide the implementation from other projects.
- Don't have any executable binaries, so no files that contains the **main** **func**.

---

```
 ~/$GOPATH/
    bin/
    pkg/
    src/
      repository_remote/
        user_name/
            project_name/
              internal/
              other_pkg/
```

---

### Single Project

- Projects such as [hugo](https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo), [etcd](https://github.com/coreos/etcd) has a **single** main func in root level and.
- Target is to generate one single binary

### Tooling Projects

- Projects such as [kubernetes](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes), [go-ethereum](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum) has **multiple** main func organized under a package called **cmd**
- `cmd/` package manages the number of binaries (tools) that we want to build

---

```
 ~/$GOPATH/
    bin/
    pkg/
    src/
      repository_remote/
        user_name/
            project_name/
              cmd/
                binary_one/
                   main.go
                binary_two/
                   main.go
                binary_three/
                   main.go
              other_pkg/
```