# Strange golang package import issue

Tags: go

Here is the directory tree:

```
+/project  
  +---/bin  
  +---/pkg  
  +---/src  
    +---/client_test  
      +---client_test.go  
    +---main.go
```

In main.go:

```
package main
import ("client_test")
func main() {
  client_test.Send()
}
```

In client_test.go:

```
package client_test
func Send() {
}
```

Error:

```
src/main.go|8| imported and not used: "client_test"
src/main.go|32| undefined: client_test
```

I've read [How to use custom packages in golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15049903/how-to-use-custom-packages-in-golang) and I think I've had the same solution like this guy, but I just don't know how to solve this problem. Please help.

go env:

```
GOARCH="amd64"  
GOBIN="/usr/local/go/bin"  
GOCHAR="6"  
GOEXE=""  
GOGCCFLAGS="-g -O2 -fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-common"  
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"  
GOHOSTOS="darwin"  
GOOS="darwin"  
GOPATH="/Users/staff/projects/Minigame_Server" (that's exactly my working directory)  
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"  
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"  
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

Comment: What is your $GOPATH, or better yet, output of `go env`?

Comment: `import` tries to find the specified path starting from each "workspace" it extracts from your `$GOPATH`, in turn.  Judging from your tree, I'd say your `$GOPATH` has to contain `/some/path/to/project`, that is, it must include that "project" directory.  Does this hold for your case?

Comment: OARCH="amd64"
GOBIN="/usr/local/go/bin"
GOCHAR="6"
GOEXE=""
GOGCCFLAGS="-g -O2 -fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-common"
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/staff/projects/Minigame_Server" (that's exactly my working directory)
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
CGO_ENABLED="1"

Comment: GOPATH should be "/Users/staff/projects/Minigame_Server/project" then.

Comment: @ThomasKappler I don't think "project" is needed since it's not shown in official document.

Comment: @ReckHou: IMO Thomas' suggestion is correct. BTW, if you're starting with Go, I recommend to use `GOPATH=$HOME` and put package files of package `foo` in `~/src/foo/*.go`, which then have the import path `foo`. It works well for me.

Comment: I've tried @ThomasKappler 's solution but still not working, I will try to reinstall the environment.

Comment: @ReckHou, the problem is that your layout is *not* what the "official document" (I dunno what it is, but I think it's something from golang.org) talks about.  `go build` assumes your *projects* are placed under the `$GOPATH/src` but you've got the `src` directory *under* a project.  This is contrary to the policy, as your project actually looks like a workspace to the `go` tool.

Comment: same shitstorm for myself. doesn't really work like java or c# does it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> [Command go, Test packages.](http://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Test_packages)
>
> ... files with names matching the file pattern "*_test.go" ... can
>   contain test functions, benchmark functions, and example functions.

Don't use reserved names. For example, replace `client_test` with `clienttest` throughout.

Comment: After some tests this is the correct solution, thanks! PS: package name can contain "_test" but file name should not.

Answer (score 1):

OK finally I found what's wrong with my environment:

Since I'm using OS X so I used .pkg file to install go, and the GOROOT is "/usr/local/go"

Then I read another fake tutorial about GO installtion and it says I had to define GOROOT in my ~/.profile, so I added "GOROOT="/usr/local/go" inside ~/.profile, then everything went wrong.

After carefully read the official document I found this:

> The Go binary distributions assume they will be installed in /usr/local/go (or c:\Go under Windows), but it is possible to install them in a different location. If you do this, you will need to set the GOROOT environment variable to that directory when using the Go tools.
>
> For example, if you installed Go to your home directory you should add the following commands to $HOME/.profile:
>
> export GOROOT=$HOME/go
> export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin

But the problem is, it did't mention what will happen if you add GOROOT in ~/.profile after .pkg installation, and it also didn't say you can't do this.

Here is my ~/.profile look like now (being corrected):

export GOPATH=$HOME/projects/
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin

BTW: you don't NEED to make /project folder under workspace. According to http://golang.org/doc/code.html#tmp_2 , it also did't say you have to:

> The workspace directory tree now looks like this:

```
bin/
    hello              # command executable
pkg/
    linux_amd64/ 
        example/
            newmath.a  # package object
src/
    example/
        hello/
            hello.go   # command source
        newmath/
            sqrt.go    # package source
```

Comment: Are you mixing up GOROOT and GOPATH?

Answer (score 0):

If your $GOPATH is "/Users/staff/projects/Minigame_Server", your "project" absolute path should be "/Users/staff/projects/Minigame_Server/src/project".

Your import should then be `import "project/src/client_test"`.

Or, what you seem like you want to do, given that you have Go-related subdirectories "/pkg" and "/bin" under "project", set your GOPATH to "/Users/staff/projects/Minigame_Server/project"

and then you can `import "client_test"`. The basic idea is that Go will append the import string to $GOPATH/src/.

The (somewhat ambiguous, I agree) doc is here: http://golang.org/doc/code.html#tmp_2 . My guess is that you've read it which is why you've created the /pkg, /bin and /src subdirectories, but the catch is where GOPATH should be, then the implicit sublevel automatically added by Go when it looks for an import (/src is automatically added), then the import string as-is.

Answer (score -1):

You can import the package in the main by using the following code it will work
import(
"fmt"
"./client_test") 
in the main package