# imported but undefined? Go

Tags: http, import, go, package

I want to use "http" package, and try to import

```
package main

import (
    "http"
)

func main() {
    resp, err := http.Get("https://api.github.com/repos/otiai10/myFirstGo")
    if err != nil {
        // do something
    }
    if resp != nil {
        // do something
    }
}
```

and got outputs below

```
% go run httpget.go
# command-line-arguments
./httpget.go:4: imported and not used: "http"
./httpget.go:8: undefined: http
```

I saw this question : [Strange golang package import issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15405973/strange-golang-package-import-issue)

Is this the same problem? or did I use 'import' or 'http' in wrong way?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The package you want to import is called `"net/http"`, not `"http"`.  Try:

```
import (
    "net/http"
)
```

Comment: （´-`）.｡oO（ But, it seems strange that it says 'imported and not used: "http"'... "cannot import 'http'" is better, I think. Isn't it?

Comment: On go 1.1.2, running your example code yields a different (better) error:
`httpget.go:4:2: cannot find package "http" in any of: /usr/local/go/src/pkg/http (from $GOROOT) /home/username/src/go/src/http (from $GOPATH)`