# How to import a struct that is inside of other package?

Tags: struct, go

I tried to learn Go but I frequently feel frustrating because some basic features that other languages has seems not working in Go. So basically, I would like to use struct type that is 
define in other file. I was able to use functions except struct type. In main.go,

```
  package main

  import (
      "list"
  )

  func main() {
      lst := list.NewList(false)         
      lst.Insert(5)
      lst.Insert(7)
      lst.InsertAt(2, 1)
      lst.PrintList()
  }
```

This works perfectly (and all other functions) as I expect (list is in $GOPATH). In package list, I defined struct as follow:

```
type LinkedList struct {
    head    *node
    size    int
    isFixed bool
}
```

I wanted to use this struct in other struct, so I attempted to do something like this,

```
type SomeType struct {
    lst *LinkedList
}
```

But unfortunately, I got error that the type LinkedList is not defined. How can I use a struct that is defined in other package?

Comment: Does [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15051192/2908724) answer your question?

Comment: Nope. As I said, every other functions works except directly using struct type. And that post is about importing other file, I didn't get any error about finding package.

Comment: As long as the name of the struct has an uppercased first letter it should be accessible using the namespace name like @tobi showed.

Comment: name of struct has to be uppercase?

Comment: @REALFREE Go decides whether something is public or package-private by the case of the first letter of the variable. Which is annoying to people who want crazy variable names, but it's a quite useful convention otherwise.

Comment: @Cubic I'd rather design to use keyword something like private and public, which explicitly make it understandable. But its Go's way, I'm buying it xD

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `LinkedList` type is in the `list` namespace, so change your usage of the type to:

```
type SomeType struct {
    lst *list.LinkedList
}
```

Comment: @REALFREE, "Effective Go" [provides an answer](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#package-names). Please consider reading this document before seriously dabbling with Go.

Comment: @kostix well thx I skimmed through it but maybe I missed that part

Comment: @REALFREE I had the same issue when starting, it's hard to memorize all the idiosyncrasies of Go, implicit export semantics is unusual, but now you will remember it forever

Comment: Is there a way to refer to the types imported from a package without the fully-qualified package identifier? I've tried `type T package.T` however, if I have a functions associated with `package.T`, `T.functionname()` will be considered undefined. Any clue on this?