# How to import local files in Go?

Tags: import, go

I would like to organize my Go code into smaller chunks. Lets assume I am writing a web application that follows the MVC pattern. I would like to organize my code like this:

```
main.go
controllers/whatever/whatever.go
models/whateverelse/whateverelse.go
```

And than in main.go I would like to:

```
import "controllers/whatever"
```

Is this possible with Go? It seems the only option, that does not make too much sense is to put the the files into the GOPATH/src folder. In that case I need to set the git repository to track the $GOPATH/ instead of just tracking my project that is $GOPATH/src/github/username/project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use custom packages in golang?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15049903/how-to-use-custom-packages-in-golang)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution came from IRC thanks to jaw22:

```
import "github.com/yoursuername/yourproject/yourlib"
```

Answer (score 3):

The solution you have could definitely work if you have the standard `github` directory structure.  However, I would like to point out that to import a `go` library, you just need to specify the path to that library starting from the directory below `src`.

If your project library has the path:

```
src/yourproject1/controllers
```

and your main code has the path:

```
src/yourproject2/main.go
```

In main.go, you simply need to say:

```
import "yourproject1/controllers"
```