# Internal packages in Go

Tags: go, import, package

How to import internals packages in Go ?

```
import (

    "runtime/internal/atomic"
    "runtime/internal/sys"
)
```

Like this without get a error:

> imports runtime/internal/atomic: use of internal package not allowed

And use internal funcs in a main package ?

Comment: You don't. They're internal packages, which mean they can only be _internally_. https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Internal_Directories

Comment: Well, what do you think why these packages are "internal"? These are "internal" because the may not be imported from different packages. Dead simple. So the answer is: "You can not."

Comment: Make sure to set [go import path](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SettingGOPATH). See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57953217/658497

Answer (score 21):

#### [Background](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1e8kOo3r51b2BWtTs_1uADIA5djfXhPT36s6eHVRIvaU/edit)

> Go encourages structuring a program as a collection of packages interacting using exported APIs. However, all packages can be imported. This creates a tension when implementing a library or command: it may grow large enough to structure as multiple packages, but splitting it would export the API used in those additional packages to the world. Being able to create packages with restricted visibility would eliminate this tension.

#### A rule proposed to Go 1.4

An import of a path containing the element “internal” is disallowed if the importing code is outside the tree rooted at the parent of the “internal” directory.

#### Short answer

You can't (at least easily) and you shouldn't.

Comment: First part of this answer copied verbatim from :https://docs.google.com/document/d/1e8kOo3r51b2BWtTs_1uADIA5djfXhPT36s6eHVRIvaU. (Useful doc for more background).

Comment: "and you shouldn't" Why?

Answer (score 4):

I will show you how I use internal [nettest](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/internal/nettest) package:

```
// I copied nettest to vendor with `dep ensure` I think. Then:
mkdir vendor-local
cp -r vendor/golang.org/x/net/internal/nettest ./vendor-local/nettest
vim ./vendor-local/nettest/stack.go and remove import comment // import "foo" [1]
// Use full import in your go file:
import "github.com/foo-user/bar-project/vendor-local/nettest"
```

[1]: https://github.com/golang/net/blob/a8b9294777976932365dabb6640cf1468d95c70f/internal/nettest/stack.go#L6

[Docs about import comments](https://golang.org/pkg/cmd/go/#hdr-Import_path_checking)

You may find all import comments in your internal package with `grep -r "// import" ./vendor-local/nettest`

#### Why can't I copy nettest to ./vendor and use shorter import

You can, but utils like `dep ensure` that don't support local packages will purge your copy.