# Handling errors following net packet read timeout

Tags: go

I am using the `conn.SetReadDeadline` method to set the read timeout for `conn`, When `conn.Read` waits for more than the specified time, it will return and return an error of type `*net.OpError`. This error is returned by the `net` package after wrapping all non-`io.EOF` errors.

I can get the error before wrapping with `Unwrap()`. A timeout error is an error of type `*poll.DeadlineExceededError`. I use statements like this in my code to handle timeout errors precisely.

```golang
import "internal/poll"

_, err = conn.Read(p)

    if err != nil {
        if pe, ok := err.(*net.OpError); ok {
            err = pe.Unwrap()
            if timeout, ok := err.(*poll.DeadlineExceededError); ok {
                log.Error(fmt.Sprintf("%T, %s", timeout, timeout))
            }
        }
        return
    }
```

I received an `use of internal package internal/poll not allowed` error while running the program. The compiler tells me that internal packages cannot be used.

I googled and found a solution to delete the `internal` folder, is this the final solution? Will there be a better solution?

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41571946/internal-packages-in-go) re the error (short answer - you can't use it). Please provide more information on `conn` (a `net.conn` should return ["an error that wraps os.ErrDeadlineExceeded"](https://pkg.go.dev/net#Conn) if the deadline is exceeded).

Comment: I get it, I still need to read more official documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `os` package exports that error as [`os.ErrDeadlineExceeded`](https://pkg.go.dev/os@go1.18.3#pkg-variables) (check the [source code](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.18.3:src/os/error.go;l=28)). You can try :

```
if errors.Is(err, os.ErrDeadlineExceeded) {
    log.Error("Timeout error")
}
```

[edit] *actually*, after reading @Brit's comment, this is the documented way to check for that error. See the doc for [`Conn.SetDeadline()`](https://pkg.go.dev/net@go1.18.3#Conn.SetDeadline) :

> If the deadline is exceeded a call to Read or Write or to other
> I/O methods will return an error that wraps os.ErrDeadlineExceeded.
> This can be tested using errors.Is(err, os.ErrDeadlineExceeded).

---

Another indication that an error is a "timeout" error is if it has a `Timeout() bool` method, which returns `true` when called.

This is part of the [`net.Error`](https://pkg.go.dev/net@go1.18.3#Error) interface (although this interface has an extra method, which is documented as deprecated), and implemented by the [`net.OpError`](https://pkg.go.dev/net@go1.18.3#OpError.Timeout) type (and also by the internal [`poll.DeadlineExceededError`](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.18.3:src/internal/poll/fd.go;l=60;drc=2a78e8afc0994f5b292bc9a5a7258c749e43032f) type).

There are several functions ([`net.OpError.IsTimeout()`](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.18.3:src/net/net.go;l=506), [`os.SyscallError.IsTimeout()`](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.18.3:src/os/error.go;l=61) and the public function [`os.IsTimeout()`](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.18.3:src/os/error.go;l=114) for example) that implement a timeout checking by directly casting the error value to a `timeout` interface.

If you want to deal with errors that can be wrapped one into another, you may want to implement your own `isTimeout()` check using `errors.As(...)` :

```
// isTimeout : use errors.As() to unwrap errors and check if a sub error is a Timeout error
func isTimeout(err error) bool {
    var terr interface{ Timeout() bool }
    return errors.As(err, &terr) && terr.Timeout()
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/OhhKY3XsGjZ

note that :

the difference between the `isTimeout()` function above and the `errors.Is(err, os.ErrDeadlineExceeded)` call is that the latter will try to match exacly an `ErrDeadlineExceeded` (which is mostly triggered by setting `SetDeadline()` on some file-or-conn-like object), while the latter one may return true for errors that try to advertise "I'm a timeout error" for other reasons (e.g : an HTTP "408 Request timeout" response)

---

*note :* all links above refer to go 1.18.3 . Depending on the version of go you are using, you may have to adapt some of the code above (for example : the `os.ErrDeadlineExceeded` was added in [go1.15](https://go.dev/doc/go1.15#os) )