# Golang, Using a Structure or function of a main package from a sub package

Tags: go

I am trying to write a go project with several sub projects. For an simple example the project looks like this

```
Main
 |- package one
    |- package one.one
    |- package one.two
 |- package two
```

From my main package i can use any function or structure of any sub package By importing them. But My question is how can i access an struct or function of main from any sub package.

Comment: Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15051192/720999).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks. I solved this problem by using an third package. Pretty easy that way.

Comment: This is not a sufficient answer to the question, if anything @Volker 's answer is the answer if so it should be marked as such.

Answer (score 5):

By importing the "subpackages" in main. But do not produce an import cycle (Restructure your code in this case).

Note that Go has (almost*) **no** notion of _sub_package: These are all plain packages and the directory layout has *no* influence on imports and usability/accessability of exported functions, types, methods, fields, variables and constants.

*) Internal packages and vendored packages depend on directory layout.