# Debugging Go single file with IntelliJ

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, go, program-entry-point

I'm trying to launch a file in debug mode in IntelliJ.

Here is my File content :

```
package myPackage

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello")
}
```

My file is in the folder `src/myProject/myPackage`

But when I try to create a Go Application in IntelliJ, it says:

```
"Cannot find Go file with main in 'myProject/myPackage'"
```

I have already make this work but I had to put my file in a package named "main".
But now my project is growing and I need to Debug my packages separately.

Any Ideas?

Comment: [Read this](https://golang.org/doc/code.html) and troubleshoot. It's likely that this question is a near duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15049903/how-to-use-custom-packages-in-golang)

Answer (score 2):

architecture for your app need to be like that :

```
$Gopath/src/FOLDER_NAME :
|- main.go
|-- my_package/file1.go
```

in your file1.go

```
package my_package

import "fmt"

func testwork() {

   fmt.Println("it works !!")
}
```

in your main.go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "FOLDER_NAME/my_package"
)

func main() {
    my_package.testwork()
}
```

And it will work :)

Comment: Thanks, it helps a lot for understanding the concept of executing the application.
But I want to proceed unit tests and avoid the usage of the "main way".
I want to use my *_test.go associated file and make debugging and breakpoints work on my IntelliJ.

Have you any idea ?  Thanks

Comment: Have u check that ? https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin/wiki/Documentation it speak about debuging at end of doc

Answer (score 0):

Currently debugging works only for Go Application run configurations. There's a PR in progress to fix this, see [this](https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin/pull/2345).