# How to import local package in Go?

Tags: go

how can i do to import a package?

myproject

main.go

**Repository**

DBHelper.go

**Configuration**

Configuration.go

I need to call a function inside DBHelper.go from Configuration.go, how can i do it?

[I need to call Select function from Configuration.go](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMiHl.png)
Thanks! Regards!

[I Call Select but not working(undefined: DBHelper.Select in DBHelper)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXdCo.png)

Comment: import paths are defined by their directory relative to `$GOPATH/src/`. Please read ["How to Write Go Code"](https://golang.org/doc/code.html). It will explain how packages work in full.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Package imports are relative from your GOPATH

For example, if DBHelper.go uses package *"helpers"*, your import would look like this:

```
<name of project folder>/Repository/helpers
```

Here is a very similar question on the subject:
[How to use custom packages in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15049903/how-to-use-custom-packages-in-golang)

--Edit

Almost forgot, to perform the actual function call, you must use the package name / alias.

```
helpers.MyFunc()
```

Comment: DBHelper.go not use helpers, i have something like this                package Repository

import (_"github.com/minus5/gofreetds"
 "../Configuration"
 "database/sql"
 "fmt"
)
func Select(){}

Comment: @JoaquinNoé I just used package name "helpers" as an example.  Replace it with whatever your package name actually is.

Comment: I not use <name of project folder>/Repository/helpers instead of i use  ../Repository