# import code from a separate package/folder

Tags: go, go-build, go-packages

I have this directory layout:

```
/baba
   biz.go         # package baba
/hello
   foo.go         # package main
```

biz.go looks like this:

```
package baba

func Foodd(z int) int {
    return z + 5
}
```

and foo.go looks like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    log.Fatal(Foodd(3))
}
```

currently this doesn't compile because `Foodd` is not recognized. How do I import the `baba` package in `foo.go`?

I assume if I compile like so, that it will pull in the right files:

```
go build foo.go
```

Or do I need to include the files in the baba package in the `go build` command? (I would hope not).

Comment: You seem to be having a number of issues all covered in the docs. Have you gone through the intro material, like [How To Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html)?

Comment: yeah, importing code is tricky here, as is usual when learning new languages, I am just trying to figure it out

Comment: @JimB for example the baba directory and the hello directory are at `$GOPATH/src/hello` and `$GOPATH/src/baba`, so why is this hard?

Comment: I am guessing I need to do something like this `$GOPATH/src/myusername/hello` and `$GOPATH/src/myusername/baba`

Comment: There's a step by step example in the docs I linked. You're neither importing `baba`, nor are you qualifying the `baba.Fodd` identifier with the package name.

Comment: Got it thank you. I wish golang would enforce packages to match their directory names. In fact I see no reason why the package declaration exists at all. Oh well. The package name could just be the name of the directory, and we could forgo the package declaration. I wonder what the reasoning is.

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the `baba` package in order to use it from your main package. That will look something like:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/the1mills/myproject/baba"
)

func main() {
    log.Fatal(baba.Foodd(3))
}
```

Imported packages are referred to by their package name, which is usually, but not always, the last element of the import path.

Usually, people let [goimports](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports) handle finding the correct import path and automatically adding it. Your editor of choice probably has `goimports` integration.

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15051192/9609198) for some other references and how to set up your directory structure.

Comment: yes but what if the package is just local, for example, let's say the package is at `$GOPATH/src/baba`

Comment: You should not create root-level packages, even if they are just local. You can create a directory structure under a namespace of your choosing, though. See https://golang.org/doc/code.html#ImportPaths.

(For the record, it will work if you create a root-level package, but it will be difficult to maintain and will probably break. You don't have to push your code to GitHub to be able to import it locally.)