# importing custom package in Go

Tags: go

I [checked out this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15049903/how-to-use-custom-packages-in-golang) and for some reason either I was unable to comprehend properly or it didn't work

Also, Before I start, I got that How we can do it with github but I want to try it without github

To start let's say I have a main.go file

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "subpack"
)

//You Import packages without using comma in Go, rather space or new line
//In VS Code, if you use aren't using the package and run then it will automatically removie it

func main() {
    fmt.Println("hello world")
    //We use math.Floor to round the nunmber
    fmt.Println(math.Floor(2.7))
    fmt.Println(math.Sqrt(16))
    fmt.Println(subpack.Reverse)
}
```

Notice  `subpack` here, it is the custom package I made. The subpack exsist like this

[image]

And contains the following code

```
package subpack

//If we make this in the same root level of our main it will throw an error

func Reverse(s string) string {
    runes := []rune(s)
    for i, j := 0, len(runes)-1; i < j; i, j = i+1, j-1 {
        runes[i], runes[j] = runes[j], runes[i]
    }
    return string(runes)
}
```

running our go is throwing following error

```
cannot find package "subpack" in any of:
        /usr/local/go/src/subpack (from $GOROOT)
        /Users/anilbhatia/go/src/subpack (from $GOPATH)
```

**Question:** Is it possible and if yes, How to use custom package without github and without making it in the GO main folder rather by simply referencing the folder containing our `go` file from the directory we are working.

Comment: Go doesn't really have a concept of "subpackages". In order import a package, you need to reference the fully qualified import path. So for example, if your main package has an import path of `github.com/me/mycoolprogram`, you would do `import "github.com/me/mycoolprogram/subpack"` in your `main.go`.

Comment: @JoelCornett  since even you happen to work on Javascript, For a person coming with a background of Js and is habitual of creating helper functions (specific for a project) and then importing it and using them. How can they have a way around?

Comment: Also, I don’t want my code to be on GitHub.

Comment: There is no "I want" and "how to circumvent the proper way". You do not need to upload you code to github but you **must** layout you code in GOPATH as described in How to Write Go Code. There is nothing to change here.

Comment: u need to put your project in `$GOPATH/src`..then `import "yourprojectname/subpack"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error shows, the compiler cannot find `subpack` from either

> /usr/local/go/src/subpack (from $GOROOT)

where the standard library packages (such as `fmt`, `strings`) are, or

> /Users/anilbhatia/go/src/subpack (from $GOPATH)

where user installed/defined packages are.

To make the import work, you just need to include the relative path of the `subpack` package (relative to `$GOPATH/src`) in your `main.go`

Suppose your `main.go` is in `/Users/anilbhatia/go/src/parentpack`, then its import should be

```
import "parentpack/subpack"
```

If I understand you correctly, you want the caller of `subpack` (say `main.go`) to be in an unrelated location of `subpack`. This actually works out of box. Your `main.go` could be located anywhere. When you compile it, the compiler sees the import path of `parentpack/subpack`, and goes to `$GOPATH/src` and `$GOROOT/src` to find it.

For more information about the source code organization and some typical examples, you can run

```
 go help gopath
```

in your shell.

Comment: Can you please do that same and update in your answer?

Comment: where is your `main.go` located?

Comment: then how will I perform I execute my `fmt.Println(subpack.Reverse("yollo"))` ? here subpack was earlier coming from `import "subpack"`
Also my `main.go` is at `Macintosh HD⁩ ▸ ⁨Users⁩ ▸ ⁨anilbhatia⁩ ▸ ⁨Desktop⁩ ▸ ⁨go⁩ ▸ ⁨packages⁩`

Comment: You need to do some file organization. Your packages should be located in `$GOPATH/src`, that's how the compiler finds where the importable libraries are. So you can either move your packages to the current `$GOPATH/src`, or add more path for `$GOPATH`.

Answer (score 1):

The starting point is $GOPATH/src not your project's folder.
So you should use

```
import "myproject/subpack"
```

instead of :

```
import "subpack"
```

Comment: then how will I perform/execute my `fmt.Println(subpack.Reverse("yollo"))` ? here subpack was earlier coming from `import "subpack"`

Comment: @KuchBhi Sorry I can't understand your question

Answer (score 0):

For some reason all the answers to this question are more than 2 years old and outdated. You can definitely do that now. I think there was a change in a recent version of Go that allows importing custom packages that are not in `$GOPATH`. You can do what you want to do simply by importing your "subpackage" like this in the main.go:

```golang
import "./subpack"
```