# Golang - How must I arrange my workspace for a package with a sample program?

Tags: go

I'm still trying to get my head around the Go workspace layout. I have a package, `todinfo` and a sample program which uses it, `untod`.

I currently have this arrangement of directories:

```
$GOPATH
+- bin...
+- pkg ...
+- src
   +- github.com
      +- longborough
         +- (others)...
         +- todinfo
            +- todinfo.go
            +- untod.go
```

I originally developed these two programs in separate directories. However, since `untod` is really part of the todinfo package, it seems more sensible to package it up as a single project, in the same directory.

But when I try to install (I've wrapped the reply onto three lines for clarity):

```
D:\Development\Go\src\github.com\longborough\todinfo>go install
 can''t load package: package github.com/longborough/todinfo: 
 found packages todinfo (todinfo.go) and main (untod.go) 
 in D:\Development\Go\src\github.com\longborough\todinfo
```

I hope I'm mistaken, but this smells a bit like Java, at least to the uninitiated.

What am I doing wrong? What Go commands should I use to install the package and then install the sample? Or, what is the correct directory arrangement?

Comment: The go tools expect 1 package per directory. Everything in `todinfo` either need to be `package todinfo` or `package main`.

Comment: The document [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html) describes how to setup a workspace.

Comment: @JimB That's precisely what I've got. `todinfo.go` has `package todinfo` and `untod.go` has `package main`.

Comment: @MuffinTop I had already read that document before coming here. It doesn't address my use case.

Comment: @Brent.Longborough: no, they both need to be the *same* package, if they are in the same directory. You can't have both `package todinfo` and `package main` in the same directory.

Comment: The [section on libraries](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Library) in code.html shows how arrange a workspace with a package and a program.

Comment: @Brent.Longborough -- note JimB's first comment says "1 package per directory," not "1 per file." It's common to put commands under a `cmd/[binary name]` dir; see [the top answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14867452/what-is-a-sensible-way-to-layout-a-go-project) for more.

Comment: @Jimb Thanks for the clarification. I missed the *either*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This got me too. Think of it this way: `untod` is not part of the `todinfo` package, it's a consumer of the `todinfo` package (library). In fact, `main` is not really a package at all, just a marker to say that it's got an entrypoint and should be compiled into a binary.

TLDR: you can put `untod` anywhere. In the root is probably sensible: it will then be named whatever the last dir component of your `$GOPATH` is. Alternatively, put it in `cmd/untod/untod.go` if you've got multiple binaries.

After some more development, you might consider making a separate repo like `github.com/longborough/todinfo-bins` to keep them apart.

[Dave Cheney has some decent advice on the subject.](http://dave.cheney.net/2014/12/01/five-suggestions-for-setting-up-a-go-project)

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I've moved `untod.go` to `github.com/longborough/todinfo/untod/untod.go` -- solved, and still part of the todinfo repo!!

Comment: Yep, that works too. It's just my personal preference to keep it close and separate.