# Go project structure to produce library and cli with the same name in single repository

Tags: go

How to setup project structure to produce library and cli with same name in
single repository?

Suppose my project name is `project`. I want to make it importable with name
`project` and have executable binary with name `project` when installed with
`go get`. My setup currently is like this:

```
host.com/project/
    project/
        main.go
    core/
        project.go
```

Then, when installed with:

```
go get host.com/project/project
```

it installs `project` as executable which pulls `core` as dependency. In
`core/project.go` file, the package has this:

```
package project
```

The problem is it is imported with:

```
import (
    "host.com/project/core"
)
```

And it exports `project` as name space not `core` which violates go's convention.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This isn't a convention, and you may do however you like, but it's a common practice to have a `cmd` folder in the project root, and all the executables go under that, each in is own folder.

So a good solution in your case could be simply:

```
host.com/project/
    cmd/
        project/
            project.go
    filea.go
    fileb.go
```

In `filea.go` and `fileb.go` the package declaration should be:

```
package project
```

In `cmd/project/project.go` package and import declaration should be:

```
package main

import "host.com/project"
```

Of course if your project is more complex, you may create further packages under the project root, and it may have multiple commands (multiple `main` packages), e.g.:

```
host.com/project/
    cmd/
        project/
            project.go
        prjtool/
            prjtool.go
    packagex/
        x.go
    packagey/
        y.go
    filea.go
    fileb.go
```

An example following this layout is the very popular Go Delve debugger (4.5k stars currently), available at https://github.com/derekparker/delve.

A very complex repository example is the `golang.org/x/tools` package which is a collection of multiple, essential Go tools, available at https://github.com/golang/tools/. Its `cmd` folder contains more than 20 subfolders (commands), many of the tools (`main` packages) even consist of multiple `.go` files (but each using `package main` declaration, forming a single package of the executable).

Also check out the following related question: [What is a sensible way to layout a Go project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14867452/what-is-a-sensible-way-to-layout-a-go-project)