# Building all code with Go and './...'

Tags: linux, bash, go, command-line

According to [Ethereum Developers' Guide](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Developers'-Guide):

> You can build all code using the go tool, placing the resulting binary
>   in $GOPATH/bin.
>
> ```
> go install -v ./...
> ```

What does `./...` do in the context of:

```
go install -v ./...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That will install any "`main`" packages found in the current or subdirectories,

"subdirectories": that is what the `./...` syntax means.
It forces `go install` to consider not just the current folder/package ('.'), but also the ones in the sub-folders: "`...`"

See "[What is a sensible way to layout a Go project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14870666/6309)": you can have multiple packages "`main`", in a library driven development:

> Moving the `main.go` file out of your root allows you to build your application from the perspective of a library. Your application binary is simply a client of your application’s library.
>
> Sometimes you might want users to interact in multiple ways so you create multiple binaries.
>   For example, if you had an “adder” package that that let users add numbers together, you may want to release a command line version as well as a web version.
>   You can easily do this by organizing your project like this:

```
adder/
  adder.go
  cmd/
    adder/
      main.go
    adder-server/
      main.go
```

> Users can install your “adder” application binaries with “go get” using an ellipsis:
>
> ```
> $ go get github.com/benbjohnson/adder/...
> ```
>
> And voila, your user has “adder” and “adder-server” installed!

Similarly, a `go install -v ./...` would install “adder” and “adder-server” as well.

Note: the `-v` print the names of packages as they are compiled.