# go get with multiple projects in workspace

Tags: go

In Go, the workspace contains the src, pkg and bin directories. How do I create multiple projects in the workspace, each with its own src, pkg, bin directories, such that I can 'go get' packages into the pkg directory of a particular project.

Comment: As @jnml pointed out, the way the doc defines workspace is confusing. I prefer to think of the src directory as the workspace. This answered my question perfectly: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9986574/1375688

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably do not need that. Let's forget also the word "workspace" it's probably only confusing you.

If you set your GOPATH environment variable that that's all you actually need to have multiple projects independently sitting on you hard disk.

For example, having `export GOPATH="$HOME"`, and performing

```
$ go get github.com/foo/bar
$ go get github.com/baz/qux
```

Your directory tree will be

```
$GOPATH/pkg...
        compiled packages
$GOPATH/src/github.com/foo/bar
        bar.go
$GOPATH/src/github.com/baz/qux
        qux.go
```

More details [here](http://golang.org/doc/code.html). Note that it *does* talk about workspaces, but I still consider that fact very unfortunate. The earlier versions of that doc did not use nor define the concept and they were useful anyway. That's IMO a proof of it (the workspace) being redundant.

Comment: So I can just import "$GOPATH/src/github.com/foo/bar" in any file?

Comment: @tldr: Drop the `$GOPATH/src/` part from the import statement and you're good to go ;-)

Comment: But that would fetch it from the master branch in the github repo. What if I want to use the version that I got from 'go get'?

Comment: @tldr: Then you have to import your fork which, of course, has a different import path because is sits in a different node of you `$GOPATH/src/` tree. Have you read the above linked document "How to Write Go Code"?

Comment: I see. I haven't read that document. Thanks for pointing me to it.

Comment: I read the document, and I'm a bit unclear about something. If I import github.com/foo/bar, does it download it every time I compile (even if the binary is already there)?

Comment: @tldr: Only `$ go get github.com/foo/bar` ever downloads. No other go command does that, so it's under your explicit control.

Comment: I see. So the actual 'workspace' is my src directory, and the directories inside it are my projects. When I build the projects, their binaries are placed in the corresponding folders inside pkg and bin directories. For example, if I have a directory 'hello' inside the src directory, I can think of that as my 'hello' project. When I build and install, binaries for the main package go in bin/hello and for others in pkg/hello. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

`go get` is not intended to be used that way.

all `go get` packages land in `$GOPATH/*` as described here: http://golang.org/doc/code.html#remote and there is no concept of separate workspaces.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want several "workspaces": Have several entries in GOPATH (separated by ":" on unix).
(But most just keep everything under one GOPATH).

Remember that `go get` fetches packages *only* into your first GOPATH entry.

The other entries can be used as "seperate workspaces".