# Organizing a multiple-file Go project with private support files

Tags: go

Following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20188012/247002) I have created the following project structure:

```
.
├── bin
├── pkg
└── src
    └── github.com
        └── GITHUB_USERNAME
            └── PROJECTNAME
                ├── lib
                │   └── model.go
                │   └── ... .go
                ├── LICENSE
                ├── README.md
                └── PROJECTNAME.go
```

- `PROJECTNAME.go` has the package `main`
- `model.go` has the package `PROJECTNAME`

In the `PROJECTNAME.go` I am importing the follwing:

```
import(
    'github.com/GITHUB_USERNAME/PROJECTNAME/lib/model'
)
```

but when I run `go build` I get the follwing error:

```
 cannot find package "github.com/GITHUB_USERNAME/PROJECTNAME/lib/model" in any of:
    /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/github.com/GITHUB_USERNAME/PROJECTNAME/lib/model (from $GOROOT)
    /home/USERNAME/go/src/github.com/GITHUB_USERNAME/PROJECTNAME/lib/model (from $GOPATH)
```

How must the packages names be to import correctly? Are there any other strategies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package import paths are defined by directory names, not file names.

The correct import path is `"github.com/GITHUB_USERNAME/PROJECTNAME/lib"` and all of the go files in that folder must have the same `package` clause at the top.

The identifier after the package clause is what identifier will be imported into the package that imports it. So if it's `package foo`, you can access the `Bar` identifier by `foo.Bar` in the importing code.

By convention, authors typically use the last part of the import path as the `package` name, so in this case, you should have `package lib` at the top of all of the Go files under the lib folder.

Comment: Hi. I'm not sure the wording is correct when you say the import path is fully based on folders. From the docs "Go's convention is that the package name is the last element of the import path". So the containing folder doesn't have to match the package name necessarily.

Comment: The import path _is_ fully defined by the folder. That doesn't have anything to do with what _package_ is defined by the go files _inside_ of that folder. Import path is totally unrelated to package name as you have noticed. Can you point out more specifically what I said that caused the confusion?

Comment: I think I understand what you're claiming better, but consider the package `github.com/golang/glog`. The file `glog.go` would exist as `$GOPATH/src/github.com/golang/glog/glog.go` and declare `package glog`. You would import this with `import "github.com/golang/glog"`, not `import "github.com/golang/glog/glog"` even though `glog` is the package. If `glog.go` declared `package foo`, you would still import it the same way, but the identifier imported would be `foo` instead of `glog`. Does that make it more clear?

Comment: Yep. I think it was just the wording.

Answer (score 1):

Two things here:

1. You missed "project" during the import. Use `github.com/GITHUB_USERNAME/PROJECTNAME/lib/model`
2. Minor: Naming the package github.com/GITHUB_USERNAME/PROJECTNAME/lib/model "PROJECTNAME" seems strange. How about lib or model?

Comment: Thanks for your help! 1. Sorry that was my fault. I have tried a lot of combinations and copied the wrong output ;) I have replaced it with the current output 2. The ```model``` should be a private file, that won't be used in other projects.

Comment: There is no notion of a "private package" in Go. All you can do is "not use" it elsewhere, but this cannot be enforced.

Comment: I meant quote:```if they are not intended to be imported by another project```

Answer (score 1):

Your import statement from your main package should read

```
import(
    "github.com/GITHUB_USERNAME/PROJECTNAME/lib/PROJECTNAME"
)
```

You said your model.go uses PROJECTNAME as the package. So you don't actually name a file in your import path. The last component should be the package name.  That means you can have a number of go files in the lib directory all with PROJECTNAME as the package.