# Go: how many packages per project

Tags: go, project-management, package, directory-structure

While working on my Go project today, I realised I had ran into a small problem. I had a `package` that had a `struct` that held a pointer to a struct from another `package`. However, that `package` also made use of a struct from the other package. In C and C++, this wouldn't pose an issue, as I'd use a header guard. However, in Go, such a program won't compile due to infinite `import` recursion.

This made me wonder, are there too many packages in my project? Should I favour bigger packages? I've always been told that each package should be specifically focused on one thing.

Right now, my structure is like this.

```
game/                  <-- imports engine, needs to access the resource manager a lot
    video/             <-- rendering goes here
        renderer.go
        shader.go
        scene.go
        ...
    engine/            <-- imports video, file, etc
        root.go        <-- contains a Root struct, handles initialisation etc
        resource.go
        ...
    file/
        dds.go
        config.go
        resource_list.go
        script.go
        ...
    main.go
    ...
```

That said, here are my questions:

- **How would you solve this?** Would you combine the `video` and `engine` packages? Redesign your program so that `video` no longer depends on `engine`?
- **How do you decide when it's appropriate to make a new package?** Do you base it on functionality? Do you group it by category?
- **How much use do you make of the `main` package?** I personally tend to get out of it as quickly as possible, maybe because I'm too used to OOP.

Comment: Package organisation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20394211/6309, http://stackoverflow.com/q/9985559/6309. You can have multiple main packages in different folder ("command" pattern)

Comment: Also useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14870666/6309

Comment: Protip: whenever you call something "engine" it does too much.

Comment: @rightføld It was just a name for lack of a better word, it's actually a really small package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As these questions are rather broad and **project-specific**, I can only hope this is of any help:

- Personally, I would try to create a third package on which both `video` and `engine` can rely. Depending on the project though, this might be a difficult thing to do, and they might need to be merged.
- A new package is usually about one specific task. Depending on the project, this might be database I/O, including all models as well - but it might also be a package that's just about reading configuration files from the disk.
- As I've built mostly web-apps, I use the `main` package to get things started: listening to ports, calling other functions, making sure database connections are closed properly, etc.

---

Example (not sure if helpful? )   :

I once had a package that was just about configurations (`config`), which referred to the rest of the packages (for some reason). The other packages however, depended on those configurations inside `config`. This is where the `main` package can come in handy: linking the `config` package with the other packages, by means of parameters.

---

The comment from VonC is also very useful and elaborate. It will probably help you more than this.

Comment: As a general principle, if two packages are mutually dependent it is typically possible to break the cycle of dependencies by adding a third, subsidiary, package. The same principle can also apply to mutually dependent goroutines that would probably deadlock. Adding a third 'service' goroutine is one of the ways to solve a deadlock caused by mutually-dependent goroutines. There is a common pattern here.