# Correct structure of Golang repository

Tags: go, repository

I am starting in Golang development. Right now my boss gave me the repository of a project that other developer made, now he's gone of the company and I am not able to ask him some things related to it. Right now I have a confussion about the project structure that he pushed to the repo, the structure is the next:

```
 |-MyApp
 |--bin
 |--pkg
 |--src
 |----api (the code of the app)
 |----github.com
 |----golang.org
 |----gopkg.in
```

To me, it's exaclty as the estructure of the Go, 1.- in the repo should not be only the *api* folder?
If I go to the api folder and make `go run main.go` I get a message that some packages are not found even when they are in the folder, 2.-how I specify the packages in the go run command?

3.- Is a good practice to set this kind of structure for the golang projects? I see in the code that he exported the packages only with "package1", if I copy and paste the code of the app inside the golang workspace then I have to specify the name of the folder to export the packages, example: "myApp/package1" so there I have that doubt. Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Organizing a multiple-file Go project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9985559/organizing-a-multiple-file-go-project)

Answer (score 2):

That all depends. There is not a single right way for everything.

It seems as if this repo decided to vendor everything, the whole GOPATH. That is okay but with the "modern" `vendor` folder today one would do it probably differently.

Never do `go run`. That's for toy programs only. Build your software with `go build` and `go install`. These command work on package path.

For everything else: Please see the official documentation https://golang.org/doc/code.html and stick to it (which means you should move stuff around a bit).